# How to do reverse search and find particular character in nth place and delete characters after that

Tags: batch-file

Actual:

```
ABCDEFGHIJ_CPW_ABC_KT_#ABCD_ABCDEFGH_ABCDEFGHIJKL L01_10_18_2017_02_53_22_015_10_244_36_7.xml
```

Need:

```
ABCDEFGHIJ_CPW_ABC_KT_#ABCD_ABCDEFGH_ABCDEFGHIJKL L01.xml
```

Want to delete everything upto .xml from 11th "_" from reverse.

This is a sample file name format. I have like 10-15K files in a directory. And I need to rename/change all the files. Basically need to delete from "_"(after L01) to ".".

Comment: And you've tried what, exactly? Please check your transformation. You start with `L01_10` and end up with `L10` Should that be `L01` or do you want the `L` and the `10` from the next group?

Comment: Where is the data string? _file/directory name, file content, value of environment variable, output of command etc._.

Comment: Is it as simple as grabbing all of the file name up to the first space and then grabbing up to the next underscore after the space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice challenge...

You have to involve a little bit of mathematics (probably much simpler, if you'd use a language with REGEX support)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=11
set "string=ABCDEFGHIJ_CPW_ABC_KT_#ABCD_ABCDEFGH_ABCDEFGHIJKL L01_10_18_2017_02_53_22_015_10_244_36_7.xml"
echo %string%
call :remove "%string%" 11
echo %return%
goto :eof

:remove [String] [Integer]
set "name=%~n1"
set n=0
for /l %%i in (150,-1,0) do (
  if "!name:~%%i,1!" equ "_" set /a n+=1, p[!n!]=%%i
)
set /a x=%2-1
set pos=!p[%x%]!
set return=!name:~0,%pos%!%~x1
```

The called subroutine counts the `_` and remembers each position. So we can "easily" calculate the position where the string should be cut.

Not a beautiful or obvious code, but - well, we are in batch...

You may have to adapt the `150` to a number greater than the longest possible string (filename, as your example suggests).

**Edit:** to process all filenames in the folder, just put another `for` around:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=11
for %%f in (*.xml) do (
  echo %%f
  call :remove "%%f" 11
  echo !return!
)
goto :eof

:remove [String] [Integer]
set "name=%~n1"
set n=0
for /l %%i in (150,-1,0) do (
  if "!name:~%%i,1!" equ "_" set /a n+=1, p[!n!]=%%i
)
set /a x=%2-1
set pos=!p[%x%]!
set return=!name:~0,%pos%!%~x1
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working. But how can I run it for 10-15K files in a directory.

Comment: Thank you very much Stephan!! It worked for me. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

In this method each underscore separated token is joined in `tail` string, but when the number of joined tokens reach a given number (11 in this example), the first token is also removed from the string; the final result is have the 11 last tokens in `tail` string. After that, such last tokens are removed from original input string.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "input=ABCDEFGHIJ_CPW_ABC_KT_#ABCD_ABCDEFGH_ABCDEFGHIJKL L01_10_18_2017_02_53_22_015_10_244_36_7.xml"

echo Input ="%input%"
set n=11
set "tail="
for %%a in ("%input:_=" "%") do (
   if !n! gtr 0 (
      set "tail=!tail!%%~a_"
   ) else (
      set "tail=!tail:*_=!%%~a_"
   )
   set /A n-=1
)
set "output=!input:_%tail:~0,-1%=!.xml"
echo Output="%output%"
```

In shorter form:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "input=ABCDEFGHIJ_CPW_ABC_KT_#ABCD_ABCDEFGH_ABCDEFGHIJKL L01_10_18_2017_02_53_22_015_10_244_36_7.xml"

echo Input ="%input%"
set n=11
set "tail="
set "aux=%input%_"
set "token=%aux:_=" & (if !n! gtr 0 (set "tail=!tail!!token!_") else set "tail=!tail:*_=!!token!_") & set /A n-=1 & set "token=%"
set "output=!input:_%tail:~0,-1%=!.xml"
echo Output="%output%"
```

In this simpler method the number of the separating underscore is calculated and used to eliminate the section after that from the original string. However, this method only works when the number of tokens to preserve is less than 32:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "input=ABCDEFGHIJ_CPW_ABC_KT_#ABCD_ABCDEFGH_ABCDEFGHIJKL L01_10_18_2017_02_53_22_015_10_244_36_7.xml"

echo Input ="%input%"
set n=-11
for %%a in ("%input:_=" "%") do set /A n+=1
for /F "tokens=%n%* delims=_" %%a in ("%input%") do set "output=!input:_%%b=!.xml"
echo Output="%output%"
```